# injectJs with PhantomJs and CasperJs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to use CasperJS to scrape a website that has dynamic content and am failing so far. The website uses a couple of js libaries(e.g. Prototype) to use autocomplete to create content. I am therefore trying to insert some values and trigger events to set off the content creation. Inserting and triggering events works fine, but no content is created.

I am new to CasperJS and found that it has problems with relative paths to the libaries. I suspect that my problem arises from the libaries not loading properly in my page environment. I therefore tried to use `injectJs` to inject them like this

> // ... create casper and do some other stuff
>
> casper.then(function() {
>
> ```
> this.echo(this.page.injectJs('http://www.my-website.com/path/to/js1'));
> this.echo(this.page.injectJs('http://www.my-website.com/path/to/js2'));
>
>  });
> ```

Unfortunately this returns false for both of the functions. The path to the script is correct, where else could be the root of this problem?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe CasperJS can handle HTTP requests to inject scripts.  This is weird because they actually show this [in their FAQ on including jQuery](http://casperjs.org/faq.html#faq-jquery). However, that same FAQ says the following:

> You can't inject scripts using the HTTP protocol, you actually have to
>   use a relative/absolute filesystem path to the script resource.

Just to double check, I tried it myself using Mac OS X and your above code.  The results of echo were `false` when using a file over http and `true` when it was local.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the best way is to download the scripts and then include them from local paths.

Comment: For the records I've updated the documentation accordingly, sorry for that mistake.

Comment: I think you can use `remoteScripts` to inject non-local scripts now

Comment: You may want to look into `includeJs` which loads from an external source asynchronously, as opposed to the local, synchronous `injectJs` phantomJs method.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I Inject Jquery in Casperjs script

```
casper.options.clientScripts = ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js"]
```

**Jquery file should be on same directory where casperjs script exisit**